# How can i fix this script in roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox, raycasting

```
        if item:IsA("BasePart") then
            item.Color = Color3.new(1,0,0)
```

I want to make a mouse raycast to place colors on parts and it shows me this error.
Error:attempt to index nil with IsA

I tried to change the script a bit and it ended up not working anymore.

Comment: What is `item`? How is it defined? I think you need to share more code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: The error is telling you that the script sees the variable as nil or not defined

Comment: Why did you tag raycasting?

Answer (score 0):

the variable "item" needs to be an Instance (example a part or object)
the error is saying "item" is not an Instance please provide more information so we can help you : )